# How to get sound with KGS go server with 16.04 or higher?

Tags: sound, java, openjdk, icedtea

Before 16.04 we can get sound using the client **cgoban-h.jar** and openjdk-6 (and pulseaudio).
But no more openjdk 6 for 16.04.
The only sound working actually is the bell at the start of a game. :/

`Error loading sample: jar:file:/media/PLACARD/SOFTS/cgoban-h.jar!/org/igoweb/go/sounds/clock/ING/black.wav
Error loading sample: jar:file:/media/PLACARD/SOFTS/cgoban-h.jar!/org/igoweb/go/sounds/clock/ING/time.wav
Error loading sample: jar:file:/media/PLACARD/SOFTS/cgoban-h.jar!/org/igoweb/go/sounds/clock/ING/counting.wav
Error loading sample: jar:file:/media/PLACARD/SOFTS/cgoban-h.jar!/org/igoweb/go/sounds/clock/ING/begins.wav`

The official recommendations `javaws http://files.gokgs.com/javaBin/cgoban.jnlp` from https://www.gokgs.com/ don't work because of security.
`Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.`

And it may have the same sound problem anyway.

Anybody can play go on KGS with sound and ubuntu xenial or higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/java-XX-openjdk/sound.properties` with ***`XX`*** replaced by your Java version.

Add the following lines to the file:

```
javax.sound.sampled.Clip=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider 
javax.sound.sampled.Port=com.sun.media.sound.PortMixerProvider 
javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider 
javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider
```

Then play!

Comment: Thx. This lines are already present is the file but commented. Work with cgoban, not with cgoban-h. :/